# Rotate text 270 degrees in IE6 ONLY

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have read a few other posts on Stack Overflow and did some Googling but so far have not seen anything that is actually working.

I have an h2 I want to rotate 270 degrees in all browsers plus IE6/7. All browsers, FF, Safari, Chrome, IE7, etc., rotate the text just fine but IE6 just won't rotate 270. I can only get it to rotate 90 which isn't what I need.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.tab-content h1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=-0.00000000, M12=1.00000000, M21=-1.00000000, M22=-0.00000000,sizingMethod='auto expand');
    zoom: 1;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4b4b4c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I tried

```
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
```

as well and that will rotate it 90 degrees but not 270 like I want.

I tired with & w/o zoom:1; and I'm running out of ideas. Any one have a good grasp of rotating text in ie6? There are a lot of articles on rotating images and such but not much on text and I figured it would be the same image or heading...

Comment: If you can get it to rotate 90 degrees, what happens when you try -90 degrees?

Comment: It seems to work with my copy of IE6.

Comment: Your question title makes it sound like you want to pull a prank on IE6 users ONLY.

Comment: gosh you're brave trying stuff like this in IE6.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I should have rephrased the title to reflect that it wasn't working in IE6 only XD. However what I found was that I was using IETester as my IE6 preview. I then thought maybe its not the code thats the problem but IE tester. I fired up the ol' virtual machine that has an actual ie6 browser and sure enough looks fine! Rotated and all!

I'm not sure if thats a documented issue with IE Tester but I know for sure that if all the documented fixes for ie6 are not working in IE Tester then its time to go to a virtual PC and make sure its not IE Tester thats at fault.

Comment: Yeah, the only way to really "test" a browser is with the actual browser.  The simulators and "modes" are just not reliable enough.  MS provides [free virtual disk images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575) just for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `matrix` transformation filter that you're using can rotate by any angle, so you should be able to use this to rotate to 270 degrees if you want to. It has some quirks, but it does work. It's just a shame that the matrix maths is so painful. This article gives a very good overview of how to work out the angles: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

But if you specifically want to rotate 270 degrees, then you don't need to use the (frankly hideous) `matrix` filter, because IE also has a much more friendly `BasicImage` filter.

Try this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

The `BasicImage` filter is only useful if you want to rotate in multiples of 90 degrees. Anything else, and you need to do the matrix transform.

The `rotation=3` tells it to rotate 90 degrees, 3 times -- ie 270 degrees.

Hope that helps.